# How to Keep Button Upright When Device Position Changes

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8

I'd like to be able to allow a button that I have in my application to always remain looking like it is in the upright position, even when the device is rotated clockwise or counterclockwise. The standard app bar kind of does this with adjusting the application bar icons according to whether the device is in portrait or landscape mode, so I'd like to do something similar with a button on my page. How might I do something like this? Any recommendations into the methods? I'd like to either stick with something like what the app bar already does, or always rotate the button so it remains upright as the device rotates.

```
<Button x:Name="CameraButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="-48,0,0,-12"
                        Click="CameraButton_Click">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="/Assets/Camera_Button1.png"/>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care the rotate animation auto played by system, you can easily achieve by providing 3 different icons(Portrait, LandscapeLeft, LandscapeRight).

In Xaml, you first add your ApplicationBarIconButton into the page Resource, and change its IconUri later when OrientationChanged is fired. Hope it helps.

The project code can be downloaded here:
http://hdtp.synology.me/ApplicationBarIconDirection.zip

xaml code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="ApplicationBarIconDirection.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
OrientationChanged="PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Key="icon_arrow" IconUri="/Assets/up.png" Text="FixedUp"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
</Grid>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

xaml.cs code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace ApplicationBarIconDirection
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(this.Resources["icon_arrow"] as ApplicationBarIconButton);
        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
            {
                (this.Resources["icon_arrow"] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/left.png", UriKind.Relative);
            }
            else if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
            {
                (this.Resources["icon_arrow"] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/right.png", UriKind.Relative);
            }
            else
            {
                (this.Resources["icon_arrow"] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/up.png", UriKind.Relative);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. I could make two more buttons rotated accordingly for different orientations. I suppose what I am looking for most is how to smoothly do this, or keep the button upright as the device orientation changes in any degree. Would an animation work? What can I do to accomplish this?

Comment: If you need the button ALWAYS stay upright without any unnecessary animation, then my approach it out. You have to make your control, which looks like application bar.
Since application bar does not inherit from UIElement or FrameworkElement, it's a pain in the ass when you want to have a customized application bar.

Answer (score 0):

Application Bar has a property named SupportedOrientation which makes it change its orientation every time the orientation of the phone changes (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.orientation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) ). But, If we look at button then we see that there is neither such property named SupportedOrientation nor any other property functioning analogous to that of SupportedOrientation for applicationbar. I would hence recommend you to make your own logic according to the changes in the phones orientation.

sample logic to change orientations-

logic to rotate a button

```
CompositeTransform ct=new CompositeTransform (){Rotation=90};
               button.Rendertransform=ct;
```

Apply this on orientation changes like this

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
            {
              //apply rotation with some angle say 90
            }
            else if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
            {
              //apply rotation 180
            }
            else if(e.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp)
            {
              //apply rotation  270
            } 
            else if(e.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitDown)
            {
              //apply rotation 360
            }
        }
```

And for smoothness like that in applicationbar buttons you would have to make your hands dirty with the storyboards and animations using expression blend

Comment: Ok, and yes I am looking for logic on this topic.